# Batch-process files with find in multiple directories

Tags: bash, unix, find, batch-processing, gnu-findutils

I have a directory with several subdirs which contain `.flac` files. I want to batch convert them to `.mp3`. The path names contain spaces. Now I want to do something like this

```
find . -type f -regex .*.flac -exec ffmpeg -i {} -c:a mp3 -b:a 320k  \;
```

But the question is, how can I use `{}` and substitute `flac` for `mp3` to give ffmpeg an output file name? In bash, one could use variable substitution `${file%.flac}.mp3`, but I cannot apply this here. `sed`-based approaches don't seem to work with `find` either. 
Is there any simple solution to this?

Comment: Btw. quote `*.flac`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using bash, I'd use `globstar`, which will expand to the list of all your `.flac` files:

```
shopt -s globstar nullglob
for file in **/*.flac; do
    [[ -f $file ]] || continue
    out_file=${file%.flac}.mp3
    ffmpeg # your options here, using "$out_file"
done
```

The check `[[ -f $file ]]` skips any directories that end in `.flac`. You could probably skip this if you don't have any of those.

I've also enabled the `nullglob` shell option, so that a pattern which doesn't match any files expands to nothing (so the loop won't run).

Comment: Then you deserve my plus-one `:)`.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to use `find` (e.g., you're stuck in the past with an antique version of Bash and `globstar` isn't available — so using Tom Fenech's solution is not an option), you have to spawn a shell to do the substitution. The standard way would be:

```
find . -name '*.flac' -type f -exec sh -c 'ffmpeg -i "$1" -c:a mp3 -b:a 320k  "${1%.flac}.mp3"' dummy {} \;
```

`sh -c` will run its first argument, and the subsequence arguments are set to the positional parameters *starting from `0`*. That's why I put a dummy parameter (and I called it `dummy`, but anything else could do).

Note that in `find`'s `-name`, the argument `*.flac` needs to be quoted. For some reason you edited your post and replaced the `-name` predicate with a `-regex` predicate: it's really useless, and you still need to quote the argument anyways.

Comment: Is it not possible to write `sh -c 'ffmpeg -i "$0" -c:a mp3 -b:a 320k  "${1%.flac}.mp3"' {} \;`

Comment: @mona_sax: nope, that's not quite valid since in that case, the positional parameter `$1` is not set! maybe you mean: `sh -c 'ffmpeg -i "$0" -c:a mp3 -b:a 320k "${0%.flac}.mp3"' {} \;`, and that's perfectly valid.

Comment: Well yes !! I mean't what you've just pointed out. :). I wanted avoid using a dummy variable. This is indeed an elegant one liner :) +1

Comment: Re quoting: `-regex .*.flac` works unquoted at least on my machine.

Comment: @oarfish: that's because you don't have any hidden files with extension `flac`. Now try to create such files, e.g., `touch .gniourf.flac .oarfish.flac` and launch your command… surprise. Moreover, your regex is wrong: you will also match files like `hello-flac`, because a single (non-backslashed) dot corresponds to any character.

Comment: Yes, the pattern is not valid for all cases, but it's fine if I know what's in my directory.

Comment: @oarfish: Why don't you do it right if you know it's wrong? `-name '*.flac'` is the way to do it. Also, `-regex` is not standard (so won't work with all versions of `find`).

Comment: Is there an advantage to use `dummy {}` and `$1` over just `{}` and `$0`? Avoiding unusual usage of `$0`, maybe?

Comment: @BenjaminW.: In this case, no advantage, really. But it's useful when using the `-exec ... +` construct and you want to loop on the arguments: `find ... -exec sh -c 'for file; do echo "found $file"; done' _ {} +` (here I used the more common `_` for the dummy argument).